# Automation of Lynx

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation

I want to build a custom Wordlist for Research and therefor im scraping special Websites.
I want to:
Use Lynx from Commandline with this Command:

```
lynx -dump -listonly "example.com" | grep -E -o "http://example.com.*|http://www.example.com.*" | sort | uniq > output.txt
```

I dont want to write 5000 x this command. I would like to use a .txt file with Websites which will be read by the lynx command and all "output" should go in one file.
Can you help me to solve this? Im a noob at Linux/Ubuntu and know nothing about coding. Sorry for my language, im german.

Comment: Provide an actual example of one such URL and your expected output

Comment: Example would be something like this: https://bild.de/
Output like this:
Word1
Word2
Word3
Word4
Each Word a new Line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
cat yourdomains.txt | while read domain
do
    lynx -dump -listonly "$domain" | \
       grep -E -o "http://${domain}.*|http://www.${domain}.*" 
done | sort | uniq > output.txt
```

?

Comment: You can avoid the pipe from `cat` with input redirection : `while read domain; do` ... `done < yourdomains.txt | sort | uniq < output.txt`.